# Find $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(+\infty,+\infty)} \left(\frac{xy}{ x^2 + y^2}\right)^{xy}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Find a limit or prove that it doesn't exists:

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(+\infty,+\infty)} \left(\frac{xy}{ x^2 + y^2}\right)^{xy}$$

Comment: Hints: What if $x=y$?  Try polar coordinates.

Comment: Can you provide some context for this question?  What are your thoughts on it?  Have you tried it on your own?

Comment: To be honest, in my university we haven't used polar coordinates for such tasks yet, generally we use Heine's or Cauchy's definition.

Comment: What does $(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty)$ mean?

Comment: I assume that the limit exists and is equal to $L$ for $(x,y)\rightarrow(+\infty,+\infty)$ means that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x>N$ and $y>N$, the expression is within $\epsilon$ of $L$.

Comment: Just as a hint. $x^{2} + y^{2}$ goes to infinity much faster than $xy$. But not always.  So just compare it with $1$. See that $x^{2}+y^{2} > xy$ when we speak of postive quantitites.So it like $a^{\infty}$ with $a<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x,y)=(\frac {xy}{x^2+y^2})^{xy}$$For $x,y>0$, we have
$$x^2+y^2\geq 2xy\implies$$
$$(\frac {2xy}{x^2+y^2})^{xy}\leq 1^{xy}\leq 1$$

$$\implies 0\leq f (x,y)\leq \frac {1}{2^{xy}} $$
$$\implies \lim_{(x,y)\to (+\infty,+\infty)}f(x,y)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's try looking at this with polar coordinates:
$$
x=r\cos(\theta)
$$
and
$$
y=r\sin(\theta).
$$
Then, consider
$$
\left(\frac{r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{r^2}\right)^{r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}.
$$
Observe that 
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}(\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta))=\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)=\cos(2\theta).
$$
This has zeros at $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}$.  By direct substitution, we see that $\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$ is maximized when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}$.  Since $x$ and $y$ are both approaching $+\infty$, it is safe to consider only $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$, i.e., $x=y$.

Since we're only working in the first quadrant (at least eventually), we know that
$$
0\leq\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(+\infty,+\infty)}\left(\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)^{xy}\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{x^2}{2x^2}\right)^{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x^2}=0.
$$